# How to understand Daniel`s prayer in the context of Pauline`s teachings of being seated with and being in Christ

Tags: daniel

I am seeking a perspective that will help me understand Daniel's prayer in the context of Paul's New Testament teaching of being coheirs with Christ, being seated with Christ in the heavenly places, and also being in Christ. Is it still valid or correct doctrinal teaching that some answers to our prayers can be hindered by satanic angelic forces in the spiritual realm as in the case of Daniel 10:13?:

> "But for twenty-one days the spirit prince of the kingdom of Persia blocked my way. Then Michael, one of the archangels, came to help me, and I left him there with the spirit prince of the kingdom of Persia."

Acts 17:28–"For IN him we live and move and have our being"

Ephesians 2:6–"And God raised us up with Christ and seated us with him in the heavenly realms in Christ Jesus"

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thans for your question.  Please take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.  I am struggling to understand what you are exactly asking here - can you clarify?

Comment: Thank you. I want to know if in the new testament our prayers can be hindered by external intermediary spiritual forces since Paul says we now have direct access to God and no entity can stand between that new relationship.

Comment: Paul says he was 'delivered out of the mouth of the lion' in regard to his being brought before Caesar Augustus, so he experienced outward restriction, but that was overcome. Paul enjoins the married to mutual compatibility regarding their marriage 'that their prayers be not hindered'. You are asking a broad question that requires experienced interpretation. Up-voted (+1) but this is not a simple matter of exegesis. It is an astute question regarding union with Christ and spiritual opposition.

Comment: If you dig deeper - Saul's theology was heavily shaped by Rabban Gamaliel [Acts 22:3]. When you read Gamaliel's teachings, you will understand Paul more.

Comment: @ChurchQuestions If Paul (or Peter, or John, or James, or Jude, or Jesus himself) had desired us to study Gamaliel I think they would have told us. Instead, we have the scripture, itself.

Comment: @Nigel J - Then why do Christian theologians site the opinions of early church fathers (eusebius)? Their commentaries are also not in biblical canon. Let's not censor historical publications from Rabban Gamaliel that would help reveal the full picture of teachings shared with the apostles.

Comment: @ChurchQuestions Jesus Christ made specific choice of certain men (apostles) and it is to them that I look for Christian doctrine. I don't know these 'Christian theologians'. I know that Jesus Christ sends Gospel Ministers, and these are my guides : 'able ministers of the new testament'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between Daniel and Paul is brought about by the cross. Believers are ‘in’ Christ, and have the Holy Spirit ‘in’ them. Daniel, all Old Testament believers, interacted with a God who was ‘outside’ of them. More, Daniel was captive in a land under the control of other gods, including at one time, the prince of Persia - and it was these that interfered with the interaction between Daniel and his God.

**DANIEL 10:13** *But the prince of the kingdom of Persia withstood me twenty-one days;*

The cross made a difference. As you noted, we now have direct access. And, one reason we can is because our bodies have been ‘cleansed’, via the cross, and this now allows the Holy Spirit to indwell us

**1 COR 6:19** *Or do you not know that your body is the temple of the Holy Spirit who is in you, whom you have from God, and you are not your own?*

And, this difference ensures that our prayers can not be interfered with from any *external* factor. (But, as pointed out in another response, interference may come from us ourselves.)

Answer (score 2):

In your comment, you wrote:

> I want to know if in the new testament our prayers can be hindered by external intermediary spiritual forces since Paul says we now have direct access to God and no entity can stand between that new relationship

Here is one way that prayers can be hindered.

1 Corinthians 7:5

> Do not deprive each other except perhaps by mutual consent and for a time, so that you may devote yourselves to **prayer**. Then come together again so that Satan will not tempt you because of your lack of self-control.

1 Peter 3:7

> Husbands, in the same way be considerate as you live with your wives, and treat them with respect as the weaker partner and as heirs with you of the gracious gift of life, so that nothing will **hinder** your prayers.

We are coheirs with Christ, being seated with Christ in the heavenly places. This is a spiritual reality. However, our bodies exist in the physical reality where the demonic forces have an advantage over our physical prayer life.

The spiritual battle in Daniel wasn't about whether God heard Daniel's prayer.

Is it still valid or correct doctrinal teaching that some answers to our prayers can be hindered by satanic angelic forces in the spiritual real as in the case of Daniel 10:13?

The spiritual dynamics may be a little bit different, but yes, Satan can still block us from hearing God's reply to our prayers because of, for example, our agitated relationship with our spouse. We need to be faithful in keeping our direct communication line with God open and free from worries, etc.